# Broken links (to meta instead of main) on meta Ask page for users under 5 reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, new-users, per-site-meta

Users with less than 5 reputation can only make posts on a site's meta if it's about one of their posts on that site. The Ask page displays a list of the user's most recent posts, so they can find the one they need.

However, those links are broken: they point to the `meta` subdomain, but with paths of questions on the main site. It looks like their targets are host-relative, when they need to be absolute or protocol-relative.

> `<a href="/questions/490000/how-do-i-run-a-command-against-files-matching-a-braceglob-pattern-from-a-variab/490001#490001" class="answer-hyperlink timeline-answers">How do I run a command against files matching a brace+glob pattern from a variable?</a></b>`

[image]
[image]

The form does interpret the meta URLs as though they were links to the main site, so this will only cause a problem for users who actually follow the links. It won't be a problem for users who just copy the link to paste it into the form.

Answer (score 6):

The list now uses full URLs instead of relative ones. I've also adjusted the behavior of clicking on list entries to hopefully reduce other unexpected behaviors. See: [Link in warning about reputation limit does not lead to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369592/link-in-warning-about-reputation-limit-does-not-lead-to-stack-overflow/378839#378839)